# My java graphics.drawImage() doesn't show the image passed to it

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, awt

I'm creating a simple app in java which shows a **`JPEG`** image on the JFrame.
I created a class **`MyPanel`** Which extends **`JPanel`** and overrode the paintComponent() method:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MyPanel extends JPanel {

    public void paintComponent(Graphics graphics)
    {
        Image image = new ImageIcon("ax.jpeg").getImage();

        graphics.drawImage(image, 1, 1, this);
    }
}
```

Then I added the newly created panel to my JFrame in my main app class:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyGraphicalApp {

    public JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
    public MyPanel myPanel = new MyPanel();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyGraphicalApp myGraphicalApp = new MyGraphicalApp();
        myGraphicalApp.go();
    }

    public void go()
    {
        jFrame.getContentPane().add(myPanel);

        jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jFrame.setSize(300,300);
        jFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The problem is that it doesn't show the image at all. my image resides to my source files:

```
src
   ------- ax.jpeg
   |
   ------- MyGraphicalApp.java
   |
   ------- MyPanel.java
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you sure you want to reload the image every single time your application is rendered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you add the directory in which the image file resides to your classpath. Then load the image in your class constructor like so:

```
protected BufferedImage image;

public MyPanel() throws IOException {
    URL imageURL = getClass().getResource("/ax.jpeg");
    if (imageURL == null) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException();
    }
    this.image = ImageIO.read(imageURL);
}
```

Comment: +1 In this way you will prevent reload the image when component is resized. Also consider mention missing `super.paintComponent(g);` at the start of `paintComponent()` implementation.

Comment: @dic19 You are not strictly required to call `super.paintComponent(g)`. The API doc lists some contracts, though, in case you opt not to do so.